# Batch File to Merge PDF's

Tags: batch-file

I created the following batch file to merge all PDF's in a directory and then create a new directory, moving the result into it. *(I am using pdftk btw, which works good)*.

How do I rename the merged file with todays date? It's currently just naming it "Test.pdf".

Second question: I want to be able to run the batch file from the desktop and have it do the same processes for multiple directories without having the batch file inside a folder for it to work. So I would have to set multiple paths.

Below is the script.

```
@echo off
pdftk *.pdf cat output %fn%.pdf
ren %fn%.pdf %fn%.xxx
del *.pdf
ren %fn%.xxx   Test.pdf
mkdir "Daily Reports for Review"
move *.pdf "Daily Reports for Review"
```

Comment: You are using a variable `fn` but you are never setting it...

Answer (score -1):

```
@echo off
pdftk *.pdf cat output %fn%.pdf
ren %fn%.pdf %fn%.xxx
del *.pdf
ren %fn%.xxx   Test.pdf
mkdir "Daily Reports for Review"
move *.pdf "Daily Reports for Review"
```

Comment: Check the [Formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) and edit your answer accordingly please.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).